# Hide Keyboard on return key [UITextField] and call function after

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

So I am trying simply to whenever the user presses the return on key on a UITextField, the keyboard gets hidden, and THEN it calls a function. Right now I have:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == _currentPasswordField)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [_passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
    else if (textField == _passwordField)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [_confirmPasswordField becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self changePassword];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

But the keyboard gets hidden after the entire changePassword function has returned. How can I hide it and THEN call my function?!

Thanks!

Comment: What does `changePassword` do?  Does it take a long time to run?  Does it present a user interface?

Comment: Doesn't present a UI... just calls my server and tries to change the password for the given user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `changePassword` method takes a long time to run, because it's talking to a server over the network.

All user interface updates, such as the keyboard hiding animation, are triggered from the main thread.  When you call a slow method on the main thread, you prevent those user interface updates from happening.

You need to move the call to `changePassword` off the main thread.  There are many ways to do this.  One of the simplest ways is to use Grand Central Dispatch (GCD), like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self changePassword];
});
```

However, this is not safe unless your `changePassword` method is thread-safe, so you need to think about what you're doing in `changePassword` and what will happen it it's running on a background thread while other methods are running on the main thread.

You need to read the [*Concurrency Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), or watch some of the WWDC videos, like Session 211 - Simplifying iPhone App Development with Grand Central Dispatch from [WWDC 2010](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).